# How to compile C functions that start with __asm in arm-none-eabi?

Tags: c, arm, gnu, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to compile this PTPD code https://github.com/mpthompson/stm32_f4_ptpd . Unfortunately, it requires premium version of Keil. Therefore, I am migrating it to use arm-none-eabi and Makefile.

I have managed to get the rest of the program to compile, except for https://github.com/mpthompson/stm32_f4_ptpd/blob/master/libraries/RTX-v4.73/SRC/ARM/HAL_CM4.c .
Example problem place:

```c
__asm void rt_set_PSP (U32 stack) {
        MSR     PSP,R0
        BX      LR
}
```

This file fails with:

```c
../libraries/rtx-v4.73/SRC/ARM/HAL_CM4.c:50:7: error: expected '(' before 'void'
 __asm void rt_set_PSP (U32 stack) {
       ^~~~
../libraries/rtx-v4.73/SRC/ARM/HAL_CM4.c:72:20: error: stray '#' in program
         LSLS    R0,#31
```

It seems like it is related to the compiler (GNU compiler not supporting this syntax?) or some flags, but googling hasn't been fertile so far.

Comment: Yes, the syntax is completely different. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: IMO port it to freeRTOS

Comment: Thanks! I started to rewrite that file into AT&T syntax, but luckily I noticed that there is a GCC version of the same thing in the same repository here: https://github.com/mpthompson/stm32_f4_ptpd/tree/master/libraries/RTX-v4.73/SRC/GCC

Comment: Look at the naked attribute and put the body of the function in inline or just convert to assembler and keep the prototype.